# Azure Function TimeTrigger runs over and over again

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function called POEditorTranslations with TimeTrigger set to:

```
* */10 * * * *
```

First it was **public static async Task POEditorTranslations...**.which made several requests to external APIs which were awaited.
I noteiced then it was being executed over and over again not respecting the interval above of only running each 10th minute.

So I remade it as a very basic non async function instead to only log (*as in code below*), but still it runs over and over again?!

Function looks like this:

```
 [FunctionName("POEditorTranslations")]
    public static void POEditorTranslations([TimerTrigger("%POEditorSchedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context) //https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/
    {
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();

        log.LogInformation($"POEditorTranslations TESTING function executed at: {DateTime.Now}, POEditorSchedule: {config.GetValue<string>("POEditorSchedule")}");

    }
```

So it supposed to be running every 10th minute, but it runs over and over again?!
Immediately after it have been executed it starts over again.

**Note**: locally running it in my Visual Studio it works, but then I have a local.settings.json file which is not present in Azure.

Still as you can see I log the value of configuration key "**POEditorSchedule**" and it looks correct to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Log below showing alot of these lines that it starts all over again:

```
2023-08-24T08:30:00Z   [Verbose]   Timer for 'POEditorTranslations' started with interval '00:00:00.8937384'.
```

**2023-08-24T08:30:01Z**   [Information]   Executing 'POEditorTranslations' (Reason='Timer fired at 2023-08-24T08:30:00.9949394+00:00', Id=7a0544f4-4a28-44a4-a379-2a441edb0d82)

2023-08-24T08:30:01Z   [Information]   POEditorTranslations TESTING function executed at: 8/24/2023 8:30:00 AM, POEditorSchedule: * */10 * * * *

**2023-08-24T08:30:01Z**   [Information]   Executed 'POEditorTranslations' (Succeeded, Id=7a0544f4-4a28-44a4-a379-2a441edb0d82, Duration=1ms)

2023-08-24T08:30:01Z   [Verbose]   Function 'POEditorTranslations' updated status: Last='2023-08-24T08:30:01.0000000+00:00', Next='2023-08-24T08:30:02.0000000+00:00', LastUpdated='2023-08-24T08:30:01.0000000+00:00'

2023-08-24T08:30:01Z   [Verbose]   Timer for 'POEditorTranslations' started with interval '00:00:00.9871280'.

**2023-08-24T08:30:02Z**   [Information]   Executing 'POEditorTranslations' (Reason='Timer fired at 2023-08-24T08:30:01.9988546+00:00', Id=003f08fc-92de-4509-8fc3-fe97a0813346)

2023-08-24T08:30:02Z   [Information]   POEditorTranslations TESTING function executed at: 8/24/2023 8:30:01 AM, POEditorSchedule: * */10 * * * *

**2023-08-24T08:30:02Z**   [Information]   Executed 'POEditorTranslations' (Succeeded, Id=003f08fc-92de-4509-8fc3-fe97a0813346, Duration=1ms)

2023-08-24T08:30:02Z   [Verbose]   Function 'POEditorTranslations' updated status: Last='2023-08-24T08:30:02.0000000+00:00', Next='2023-08-24T08:30:03.0000000+00:00', LastUpdated='2023-08-24T08:30:02.0000000+00:00'

**UPDATE**

I got answer about using Environment variables instead of Configuration in Azure portal - but I do not have such menu item:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to hardcoded this cron expression in the function code? I mean `[TimerTrigger("* */10 * * * *"]` as it seems that the trigger isn't able to read the configuration properly (that's an assumption only).

Comment: Update your Cron expression to `0 */10 * * * *` in order to trigger the function in 10 minute interval

Comment: I tried it now actually and it seem to stop after executing - but still it executes like 2 or 3 times. But yes, it was an improvement so maybe it can not read configuration key from Azure Configuration as you say with "%KeyName%" syntax

Comment: "%KeyName%" will also work, you need to add KeyName to azure configuration setting and locally its working for me too [image](https://i.imgur.com/XLknM20.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have reproduced the issue at my environment but after updating the Cron expression to `0 */10 * * * *` my function started working as expected in every 10 minutes*

**`Code:`**

```
[FunctionName("POEditorTranslations")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("%POEditorSchedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"POEditorTranslations TESTING function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

***While running locally-***

**`local.settings`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "POEditorSchedule": "0 */10 * * * *"
  }
}
```

**`Local Output:`**

[image]

*After deployment I have added `POEditorSchedule`  to app setting-*

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

*1st trigger-*

[image]

*2nd trigger-*

[image]

Comment: Oh I see you add it to the "Environment variables" and I have added it in the "Configuration" part in Azure!!!

I will try the same now. Big thank you!

Comment: Hmm I do not have such menu item "Environment variables" as you have in your screenshot:

Comment: Azure environment got a makeover recently, previously it was `Configuration` but now it has changed to `Environment variables`. If you haven't updated it, then you might not see `Environment variables`. In your case you need to add the parameter in `Configuration`. But change your Cron expression to `0 */10 * * * *`  to get the function triggered correctly in every 10 minutes. If you will use `* */10 * * * *`, your function will get triggered over and over again after 10 minutes

Comment: If you will see my answer, I am using `0 */10 * * * *` Cron expression and its giving me expected result

Comment: Ah ok I see, that why a small confusion here then. Your help much appriciated, thnk you, I will mark this solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem to read configuration key properly like this:

```
POEditorTranslations([TimerTrigger("%POEditorSchedule%")]
```

When I hardcode it to:

```
POEditorTranslations([TimerTrigger("* */10 * * * *")]
```

it seem to work.

I have double checked key and value and proof is also that it is render it correct when I do the logging as you could see in my example.

Not sure how to go forward as I would like to not have it hardcoded, but for now it is ok.